# Increment reference count of Python object

Tags: python-3.x, reference-counting

I have a static method that returns a new instance of it's class.  The problem is that the instance is None in the code that called the method.  I believe this is due to the fact the instance is created in a static method so it's reference count isn't incremented and it is released before the calling code can reference it.  In C, I could call `Py_INCREF()` but I need to increment the reference count in Python code.  What do I need to do?

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def get(id: int) -> MyClass:
      myobj = MyClass().configuredata()
      return myobj
```

Comment: Did you mean `class MyClass:`? Also, can you show an example of the calling code that replicates the problem behavior?

Comment: As an aside, the incrementing the reference count is almost certainly not what you need to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is the same class.  obj = MyClass.get(2)

Comment: If this is not the solution to resolve the problem, what is the problem and the solution?

Comment: Yes, I meant class MyClass.  I corrected it.

Comment: I cannot replicate it as you've shown. When I place `obj = MyClass.get(2)` and `print(obj)` I get the object's representation.

Comment: Have you verified the change (or no change) in the reference count using ```sys.getrefcount()```? Calling ```get()``` in either the class or an instance increased the ref count for ```MyClass``` as far as I could tell.

Comment: My example above was missing the call to configuredata() which is the trigger of the issue.   When I code it as ``myobj = MyClass()``<br/>``myobj.configuredata()<br/>return myobj`` it works but ``myobj = MyClass().configuredata()
      return myobj`` does not.

Comment: `configuredata` returns None. This has nothing to do with refcounting.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was not reference counting but rather that chaining of methods called a method that did not return self but instead returned None.